# Book with a concept about accepting a bribe

Tags: story-identification, novel

What I remember about this book is:

I probably read it in the late '70s or anytime in the '80s.

It's set in the future, I seem to remember there being multiple planets.

The political situation is that things seem to have settled down: no great political agitation, everything just going along.

There is a universal basic income, so lots of people just live off that, sit around watching TV etc. all day.

A group of friends decide to start a new political party to shake things up and have some fun etc. It succeeds rather better than they had thought it would.

One very specific issue is that they made a rule, right in the beginning, that they would accept bribes and make them part of the general fund. They go on to make a lot of money for their new party doing this.

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: This reminds me of  Brin's "The Fourth Vocation of George Gustaf", but I'm pretty sure there's nothing about bribery in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222445/sci-fi-satire-book-set-in-a-post-scarcity-society/

Comment: @Lorendiac That looks like it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @DavidW That was not my understanding of the usual policy about likely duplicates. For instance, I've been known to post Story-ID question, and get a reply, as a comment, pointing out that my detailed description of what I remembered made it certain (or nearly so) that I was "duplicating" a previous question which had an accepted answer. I checked the link the commenter provided, and saw that this was correct. My question was then closed as a duplicate. And I've seen the same thing happen to several other people's questions over the years. And I've seen discusson on Meta (cont'd)

Comment: confirming that just posting a comment about a possible duplicate, with a link to the older question with an already-accepted answer, is considered the right way to go. Then the person who asked the new question can gauge whether the same answer applies. So this is what I normally do when I feel certain (or *nearly* so) that a new duplicate of an answered question has arisen. In this case, the accepted answer in the link I gave was written by yours truly, in 2019, and I'd feel very silly about posting essentially the same answer, twice, on different questions a few years apart.

Comment: @Lorendiac My apologies if I was being pushy; I don't want to imply that my position is more correct, or that I have a better understanding of policy.  (I haven't been here as long as you, so I wasn't even present for some of those discussions.)  I guess my understanding was that it didn't _hurt_ to have an answer to a duplicate, and confirmation-by-comment was just a shortcut.  And I've observed that some people seem more likely to respond to a posted answer than a comment, so after waiting a couple of hours for a response from OP, I suggested answering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126482/discussion-between-davidw-and-lorendiac).

Comment: So if I think that the 'duplicate' is indeed the answer what should I do to give credit to the answerer?

Comment: @VaughnOhlman: Personally, that's one of my arguments for people posting an answer, but generally, you state it in a comment and then people vote to close as duplicate. Do you then feel this is a duplicate?

Comment: Fuzzy... in the sense that one uses 'duplicate' here, yes. I always find it funny to see wildly differing questions marked as 'duplicate' because they have the same answers :)
7*7=42
36+6=*duplicate, see '7*7'*
:)
But the frustrating thing is I can't give credit, eh?

Comment: This was an author I don't even remember. Usually when I do this it is from some author I remember reading a lot of. But a lot of his stuff is free on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Lorendiac for the answer. This is [*Trample an Empire Down*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?458651) (1978), by Mack Reynolds.

Comment: It's more useful to add the name here; the link to the duplicate will be at the top.